# R give a result based on a condition

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would really apreciate your help.
    I have a table with IDs and the column result is touchpoint_type.
    When the ID is different to the previous one, then I give “C”, if not “I”.
    That’s my code:
    mydata_cce2$touchpoint_type<-c(0)
    mydata_cce2$touchpoint_type[1]="C"
    j = length(mydata_cce2$id_transaction)
    for (j in 2:(j-1)){

```
  if (mydata_cce2$id_transaction[j] != mydata_cce2$id_transaction[j-1]) 

    { mydata_cce2$touchpoint_type[j] ="C"

  } 

  else { 

    mydata_cce2$touchpoint_type[j] = "I"

  }

}
This is the results that I should get:
id_transaction  touchpoint_type 
    id_transaction  touchpoint_type
1   68013539    C
2   68013539    I
3   68013539    I
4   68013702    C
5   68013738    C
6   68013738    I
```

That `s the error that I get: Error: inesperado '}' in "}"

> `Blockquote`

Comment: R is upset with your very sloppy formatting. Compare [these two if-else statements](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/1f1bf203496df6fd007e4751f7b81ff7#file-if-else-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do an `ifelse()` in combination with a `shift()`.

```
#Data
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="id_transaction
   68013539    
   68013539    
   68013539    
   68013702    
   68013738    
   68013738")

library(data.table)
df$touchpoint_type <- ifelse(shift(df$id_transaction,n=1L,type="lag") == df$id_transaction, "I","C")

df
  id_transaction touchpoint_type
1       68013539            <NA>
2       68013539               I
3       68013539               I
4       68013702               C
5       68013738               C
6       68013738               I
```

Note the reason the first entry is not "C" is because its the first entry in my sample data frame. If there were something above it, it would not be NA.

Comment: Sorry MikeyMike, R says it coudnt find the function "shift". do you why is that? Thanks a lot

Comment: Its in the `data.table` package. I've updated my code. Apologies about not including that.

Comment: np! If you thought it was helpful, feel free to click on the the check next to my response.